# How to write a function that triggers two Calendar objects once every 7 days?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, calendar

I'm struggling to create a section to a program I'm writing to charge an amount to a credit card in the simulation once every 7 days. In other words, the current day will advance by one day each day and whenever it gets to the future day (set 7 days in the future) the event will occur, and the future day will be reset to another 7 days in the future. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MyClass {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
  
       int programLength = 80;
       Calendar current, future;
  
       for (int i = 0; i < programLength; i++) {
           current = Calendar.getInstance();
           future = (Calendar) current.clone();
      
           if (current.equals(future)) {
               System.out.println(i + " Success!");
               future.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
           }
      
           current.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
       }
  
     }
}
```

The output is just (i + " Success!") 80 times, as the for loop runs 80 times. I want the output to be (i + " Success!") for only one every seven times the loop runs. Help please.

Comment: `future` is always equal to `current`

Comment: The two lines where you initialise `current` and `future` need to be BEFORE the `for` loop, not inside it, otherwise you just reset them every time through.  So you could just move them up a couple of lines, and your problem would be solved.  You should also stop using `Calendar` and use `LocalDate` instead, although that's kind of a different issue.  Put those two ideas together, and you get MadProgrammer's answer.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

On each iteration of the loop, you make `future` equal to `current`

```
current = Calendar.getInstance();
future = (Calendar) current.clone();
```

So your `if` condition will always be true.

Instead, dump the `Calendar` class, it's out-of-date and error prone (and somewhat confusing to use) and start making use of the `java.time` APIs instead.

Start by seeding the current date and future date values, then on each iteration, check if they match, if they do, set the future date again. For example...

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate triggerDate = date.plusDays(7);

        for (int index = 0; index < 80; index++) {
            if (date.equals(triggerDate)) {
                System.out.println("[" + index + "] Show me the money!!");
                triggerDate = date.plusDays(7);
            }
            date = date.plusDays(1);
        }
    }
}
```

which prints

```
[7] Show me the money!!
[14] Show me the money!!
[21] Show me the money!!
[28] Show me the money!!
[35] Show me the money!!
[42] Show me the money!!
[49] Show me the money!!
[56] Show me the money!!
[63] Show me the money!!
[70] Show me the money!!
[77] Show me the money!!
```